# Criar botões para cada item de uma lista em python usando tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Desenvolvi um software que envia os dados de consumo a um banco de dados.
Fiz outra aplicação para receber esses dados e gerar um gráfico.

O meu objetivo é criar botão específico para cada dia de consumo. Porém ao criar os botões em uma lista utilizando o loop `for`, o comando envia o índice final e não o índice esperado.

Por exemplo, o primeiro botão tem índice 0, porém ao clicar nele é enviado o último índice da lista como argumento para a função que recebe o comando.

```
def tela_inicio(self):

    self.menu.destroy()
    self.menu = Tk()
    self.menu.title("Monitoramento - Sabrina")
    self.menu.geometry("1060x380+0+0")

    self.voltar = Button(self.menu, text = "Voltar", bg = "#040c31", fg = "white")
    self.voltar["command"] = self.c_menu

    self.f_dias() #Essa função me retorna os dias monitorados
    botao = list()    

    for i in range(len(self.dia)):
        #ao criar o botao o texto dele fica correto
        botao.append(Button(self.menu, text = f"{self.dia[i]}"))
        botao[i].grid()
        #A função grafico recebe o dia como argumento para plotar um grafico com os dados referente ao mesmo       
        botao[i]["command"] = lambda: self.grafico(self.dia[i])

    self.voltar.grid()
    self.menu.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver criando uma função para exibir os botões dentro do loop `while`. Os parâmetros `i` e `valor` são utilizados para recuperar a chave e o valor do dicionário `dia`.

```
from tkinter import *

dia = {1:'domingo',2:'segunda',3:'terça',4:'quarta',5:'quinta',6:'sexta',7:'sabado'}

i = len(dia)

menu = Tk()
menu.title("Exemplo - Função Exibir Botão")
menu.geometry("500x250+150+150")


def exbir_dia(valor):    
    print(valor)


def exbir_botao(i, valor):    
    botao = Button(menu, text=dia.get(i), command = lambda: exbir_dia(valor))    
    botao.grid()


while i > 0:

    valor = dia.get(i)

    exbir_botao(i, valor)

    i -= 1 

menu.mainloop()
```

Saída:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Éder, infelizmente tive um problema com meu notebook. Mas assim que tiver a oportunidade irei testar, porém olhando acredito que vai continuar com o mesmo problema. Você pode testar pra gente fazendo uma função que retorne o texto do botão clicado por favor?

Comment: Agora deu certo Jonas, quando aperta o botão imprime a chave e o valor do dicionário dia que da nome ao botão. Basta adaptar a função exibir_botão no teu projeto.

Comment: Muito obrigado, Eder! Me tirou de um bloqueio gigante. Tava travando tudo por causa disso kkk. Muito obrigado mesmo

Comment: Que bom que te ajudou Jonas, abraço e até a próxima!

Answer (score -3):

Para funcionar sempre que um botão for clicado de usar o seguinte comando:
botao[i]["command"] = lambda x=i: self.grafico(self.dia[x])

Isso irá resolver o seu problema.